# C# Session doesn't exist in current content

Tags: c#, sql, authentication, session

I want to save the userid in the session to use in the application. I gave the following code.

But getting compilation error saying The name Session doesn't exist in the current context. is there any library that I need to use?. Please advise.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    Session["Username"] = user.Text;
}
```

Comment: Are you even writing a web application? you may want to add asp.net to your tags if so. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx to see how to acquire the session variable. If you're not writing a web application, there will, almost certainly, be a better way of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry i am new to c# and i am  writing a windows form application, I need to get the login username into a label in a another form

Answer (score 3):

if it is a web application it should have worked.

anyways try adding

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"] = user.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and solved this for myself, was having the same problem until I read the MS documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.  Basically, outside of the WebForms class, you need to grab a reference to the context.  Example follows for getting and setting the sessionStorage.

`using System.Web;
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;`

Setting:
`context.Session["FirstName"] = firstName;`

Getting:
`firstName = (string)(context.Session["FirstName"]);`